# How to scale values in the heamap in row direction using Matplotlib's "imshow"?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scaling, heatmap

Are there any R like functionality (heatmap(x, scale="row",..) to scale the values in the row direction in Matplotlib?

-- Current code ---

```
im = ax_heatmap.imshow(z, aspect='auto', cmap=cmap, interpolation='nearest')
```

There is one post mentioning scaling using **vmin and vmax** parameters , but it didn't discuss how to scale in particular direction( either row or column).

Comment: There is a single color map and norm for all pixels in the image.  I do not understand your question.

Comment: @tcaswell: Sorry for confusion. I have generated a heatmap, and to highlight the row-wise pattern, I need to scale the row values before plotting heatmap. This functionality exists in R packages (like 'heatmap' package argument 'scale') and I was wondering if there is some thing similar to that in matplotlib??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do that normalization your self.  If the plotting library does it for you, getting the color bar right in all cases would be difficult.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


shifts = np.linspace(1, 50, 25)[:, np.newaxis]
x = np.arange(50)[np.newaxis, :]
data = np.exp(-(x - shifts)**2 / 50) * shifts

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1)

im1 = ax1.imshow(data, interpolation='none', cmap='viridis')
fig.colorbar(im1, ax=ax1, label='raw values')

norm_data = (data - np.min(data, axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]) / np.ptp(data, axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
im2 = ax2.imshow(norm_data, interpolation='none', cmap='viridis')
fig.colorbar(im2, ax=ax2, label='normalized by row')
```

[image]